# How to add child element after removing in javascript on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of items that dynamically changes based on select tag value. The problem is i have to remove old `<li>` and add new `<li>` tag after refresh. I used clearlist function for removal onload in body but it throws null error in x. please help. thanks

```
 var x = document.getElementById("ul1"); 
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  x.innerHTML= x.innerHTML + '<li>'+items+'</li>'
  }

   function clearlist(){ 
    var elem = document.getElementById('ul1');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
```

Comment: because you are performing the x.innerHTML after the removing it.

Comment: You've removed `ul1`. It no longer exists. `elem.innerHTML = ""` would work. Also `items` doesn't exist here?

Answer (score 2):

By using `removeChild(elem)` you are removing `<ul id="ul1">` from the DOM. Use `innerHTML` to clear the contents of the `ul` instead:

```js
function addResults(results) {
  var x = document.getElementById("ul1"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    x.innerHTML= x.innerHTML + '<li>'+results[i]+'</li>'
  }
}

function clearlist(){ 
  var elem = document.getElementById('ul1');
  elem.innerHTML = "";
}

addResults([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
clearlist();
addResults([1, 2, 3]);
```

```html
<ul id="ul1">
    
</ul>
```

Comment: The list elements grows :( older one stays

Comment: I'm calling in body tag onload